# Cannot create property 'messages' on string '{' cart:

Tags: checkout, magento2.2

I have a very annoying problem: randomly our customers get the next javascript error, which hangs the shopping process, it also appears in the cart view.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'cart' on string '{"cart":1569522511,"bss-fbpixel-atc":1569522510,"customer":1569522493,"compare-products":1569522493,"last-ordered-items":1569522493,"directory-data":1569522493,"instant-purchase":1569522493,"persistent":1569522493,"review":1569522493,"wishlist":1569522493,"rewards":1569522493,"bss-fbpixel-subscribe":1569522493,"recently_viewed_product":1569522493,"recently_compared_product":1569522493,"product_data_storage":1569522493,"paypal-billing-agreement":1569522493,"checkout-fields":1569522493,"collection-point-result":1569522493}'
```

Also the nginx log contains the following line:

```
 [26/Sep/2019:06:33:11 +0200] "GET /customer/section/load/?sections=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15%2C16%2C17%2C18%2C19%2C20%2C21%2C22%2C23%2C24%2C25%2C26%2C27%2C28%2C29%2C30%2C31%2C32%2C33%2C34%2C35%2C36%2C37%2C38%2C39%2C40%2C41%2C42%2C43%2C44%2C45%2C46%2C47%2C48%2C49%2C50%2C51%2C52%2C53%2C54%2C55%2C56%2C57%2C58%2C59%2C60%2C61%2C62%2C63%2C64%2C65%2C66%2C67%2C68%2C69%2C70%2C71%2C72%2C73%2C74%2C75%2C76%2C77%2C78%2C79%2C80%2C81%2C82%2C83%2C84%2C85%2C86%2C87%2C88%2C89%2C90%2C91%2C92%2C93%2C94%2C95%2C96%2C97%2C98%2C99%2C100%2C101%2C102%2C103%2C104%2C105%2C106%2C107%2C108%2C109%2C110%2C111%2C112%2C113%2C114%2C115%2C116%2C117%2C118%2C119%2C120%2C121%2C122%2C123%2C124%2C125%2C126%2C127%2C128%2C129%2C130%2C131%2C132%2C133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C138%2C139%2C140%2C141%2C142%2C143%2C144%2C145%2C146%2C147%2C148%2C149%2C150%2C151%2C152%2C153%2C154%2C155%2C156%2C157%2C158%2C159%2C160%2C161%2C162%2C163%2C164%2C165%2C166%2C167%2C168%2C169%2C170%2C171%2C172%2C173%2C174%2C175%2C176%2C177%2C178%2C179%2C180%2C181%2C182%2C183%2C184%2C185%2C186%2C187%2C188%2C189%2C190%2C191%2C192%2C193%2C194%2C195%2C196%2C197%2C198%2C199%2C200%2C201%2C202%2C203%2C204%2C205%2C206%2C207%2C208%2C209%2C210%2C211%2C212%2C213%2C214%2C215%2C216%2C217%2C218%2C219%2C220%2C221%2C222%2C223%2C224%2C225%2C226%2C227%2C228%2C229%2C230%2C231%2C232%2C233%2C234%2C235%2C236%2C237%2C238%2C239%2C240%2C241%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C245%2C246%2C247%2C248%2C249%2C250%2C251%2C252%2C253%2C254%2C255%2C256%2C257%2C258%2C259%2C260%2C261%2C262%2C263%2C264%2C265%2C266%2C267%2C268%2C269%2C270%2C271%2C272%2C273%2C274%2C275%2C276%2C277%2C278%2C279%2C280%2C281%2C282%2C283%2C284%2C285%2C286%2C287%2C288%2C289%2C290%2C291%2C292%2C293%2C294%2C295%2C296%2C297%2C298%2C299%2C300%2C301%2C302%2C303%2C304%2C305%2C306%2C307%2C308%2C309%2C310%2C311%2C312%2C313%2C314%2C315%2C316%2C317%2C318%2C319%2C320%2C321%2C322%2C323%2C324%2C325%2C326%2C327%2C328%2C329%2C330%2C331%2C332%2C333%2C334%2C335%2C336%2C337%2C338%2C339%2C340%2C341%2C342%2C343%2C344%2C345%2C346%2C347%2C348%2C349%2C350%2C351%2C352%2C353%2C354%2C355%2C356%2C357%2C358%2C359%2C360%2C361%2C362%2C363%2C364%2C365%2C366%2C367%2C368%2C369%2C370%2C371%2C372%2C373%2C374%2C375%2C376%2C377%2C378%2C379%2C380%2C381%2C382%2C383%2C384%2C385%2C386%2C387%2C388%2C389%2C390%2C391%2C392%2C393%2C394%2C395%2C396%2C397%2C398%2C399%2C400%2C401%2C402%2C403%2C404%2C405%2C406%2C407%2C408%2C409%2C410%2C411%2C412%2C413%2C414%2C415%2C416%2C417%2C418%2C419%2C420%2C421%2C422%2C423%2C424%2C425%2C426%2C427%2C428%2C429%2C430%2C431%2C432%2C433%2C434%2C435%2C436%2C437%2C438%2C439%2C440%2C441%2C442%2C443%2C444%2C445%2C446%2C447%2C448%2C449%2C450%2C451%2C452%2C453%2C454%2C455%2C456%2C457%2C458%2C459%2C460%2C461%2C462%2C463%2C464%2C465%2C466%2C467%2C468%2C469%2C470%2C471%2C472%2C473%2C474%2C475%2C476%2C477%2C478%2C479%2C480%2C481%2C482%2C483%2C484%2C485%2C486%2C487%2C488%2C489%2C490%2C491%2C492%2C493%2C494%2C495%2C496%2C497%2C498%2C499%2C500%2C501%2C502%2C503%2C504%2C505%2C506%2C507%2C508%2C509%2C510%2C511%2C512%2C513%2C514%2C515%2C516%2C517%2C518%2C519%2C520%2C521%2C522%2C523%2C524%2C52
```

Has anyone some glue, what's happening here??

Thank you very much for you answers!

```
at customer-data.min.js:3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this:

in vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js (about line 163)

this code was added:

```
if (typeof sectionDataIds == 'string') sectionDataIds = JSON.parse(sectionDataIds);
```

the section looks like this now:

```
/**
         * @param {Object} sections
         */
        update: function (sections) {
            var sectionId = 0,
                sectionDataIds = $.cookieStorage.get('section_data_ids') || {};
                // THIS LINE WAS ADDED
<------><------>if (typeof sectionDataIds == 'string') sectionDataIds = JSON.parse(sectionDataIds);<--
            _.each(sections, function (sectionData, sectionName) {
                sectionId = sectionData['data_id'];
                sectionDataIds[sectionName] = sectionId;
                storage.set(sectionName, sectionData);
                storageInvalidation.remove(sectionName);
                buffer.notify(sectionName, sectionData);
            });
            $.cookieStorage.set('section_data_ids', sectionDataIds);
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with Magento 2.4. So I applied quality patch. More about here: [magento quality patches](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching/mqp.html)

In my case I applied MC-41359.
Open terminal (root folder) and type:
$ ./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply  MC-41359, then run

rm -rf var/di/* generated/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento c:f

php bin/magento c:c

You can also check status of patches by typing:

$./vendor/bin/magento-patches status

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution for this problem? i'm facing the same problem with magento 2.2.8
Thank you,

Comment: try to check any modules related to FacebookPixel and check code statement as `customerData.get('bss-fbpixel-subscribe')`